# Transitive feedback arc set (TFAS): NP-complete?

Tags: np-hardness, reductions

Some time ago, I posted [a reference request](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19845/np-complete-graph-problems-about-structural-properties) for graph problems where we want to find a 2-partition of the edges where both sets fulfill a property not related to their cardinality. I was trying to prove that the following problem is NP-hard:

> Given a tournament $G = (V,E)$, is there a feedback arc set $F \subseteq E$ in $G$ that defines a transitive relation?

I do have a construction for an attempt at a proof, but it seems that that is going to run into a dead end, so I thought I might ask here to see whether I'm missing something obvious. In order to not confine your creativity to lines of thought similar to the ones I used, I won't post my attempt here.

Is this problem NP-hard? If so, how to prove it?

Comment: Just to clarify possible questions: since $F \subseteq E \subseteq V^2$, $F$ itself is a relation (as is $E$). The question is, is there a transitive $F$ such that $(V, E \setminus F)$ is acyclic.

Comment: perfect, thanks! (I deleted the comment because I wrote G=(E,V) instead of the standard G=(V,E) :-)

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is equivalent to asking whether the edges in a tournament can be partitioned into two DAGs, one of which is transitively closed.

Comment: @dspyz Yes, that would be another formulation of the problem.

Comment: idea: is it related somehow to a question on 2coloring edges or can it be stated more as a coloring problem...

Comment: @vzn I'm not sure how you could encode transitivity or acyclicity in colorings, but I may be missing something.

Comment: re dspyz's comment, there are not that many problems on DAGs that can be studied due to the complexity of them. there arent even that many theorems at all on DAGs it would seem. trees are a little more accessible. your problem (while apparently interesting as reflected in votes) seems to mix a lot of unusual elements together & not fit into any particular category.

Comment: A clarification question: Is it possible to partition a tournament into two DAGs efficiently? Or is this problem NP-hard?

Comment: @IgorShinkar the arcs of any digraph can be partitioned trivially into two DAGs: order the vertices arbitrarily; one DAG is the forward edges, the other DAG is the backward edges.

Comment: An interesting question might be if you can partition the vertices of a digraph into two sets, so that the induced digraph on each of the sets is a DAG. But this problem is not very related to OP's question, which is about partitioning the arcs.

Comment: @SashoNikolov of course!

Answer (score 4):

To add a little context, here's a construction for a graph that doesn't have a transitive feedback arc set. For this construction, I'll use the following gadget graph:

[image: gadget graph used to force implications]

This tournament has the following properties (which I checked using a program, I didn't prove it formally):

- if (2,7) is not in a given TFAS, then (1,3) is
- if (5,1) is in a given TFAS, then so is (3,6)
- if (7,3) is in a given TFAS, then (5,1) is not

or slightly abusing predicate logic notation:

- $\neg (2,7) \rightarrow (1,3)$
- $(5,1) \rightarrow (3,6)$
- $(7,3) \rightarrow \neg (5,1)$

You'll notice that for each implication, the two edges are pairwise disjoint, so the following construction works:

[image: construction for graph that doesn't have a TFAS]

I hope you can make out the idea of the graph: using the implication properties of the tournament above, we can construct a graph in which each transitive feedback arc set both includes and doesn't include the edge $A$, i.e. a contradiction, which means the graph doesn't have a transitive feedback arc set. Any completion of that graph cannot have one either since the same contradiction will remain in any completion. I left out a large number of vertices, all of which can be derived from substituting the tournament above for the implications.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow.  Is there any reason you can't just post a list of the edges so I can run it through an ASP solver and try to verify it?  According to clingo, your gadget graph has 8 different TFAS's.  Here's the smallest one: tfas(edge(5,0)) tfas(edge(6,0)) tfas(edge(7,0)) tfas(edge(6,2)) tfas(edge(7,3)) tfas(edge(1,2)) tfas(edge(1,3)) tfas(edge(7,5))

Comment: I just noticed you mentioned the edge (6,3) in the gadget graph, but the image you provided has the edge (3,6)

Comment: I figured it out, see my updated answer: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/20778/13643

Comment: @dspyz I thought the construction was clearer than just a list of the edges, since if my reasoning isn't wrong, all that would be required to verify is whether the tournament above the construction actually has those implication properties. Thanks for pointing out the mistake about edge (3,6)! I also got 8 TFAS for that gadget, the one you listed being one of them.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I constructed the graph wrong.  I fixed it and clingo now reports no TFAS.

Comment: @dspyz Thank you very much for putting this much effort into this! I was quite a bit confused since just like you, I couldn't see an error in the construction. At least that bit is settled, then.

Comment: I found one with nine vertices.  See the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I ran a short clingo program which reported no graph without a TFAS, but there was a bug.  I fixed it and now it verifies there's no graph without a TFAS for n=8 or less.  For n=9, it finds this one:

```
is_edge(edge(2,3)) is_edge(edge(1,4)) is_edge(edge(2,4)) is_edge(edge(3,5)) is_edge(edge(4,5)) is_edge(edge(1,6)) is_edge(edge(2,6)) is_edge(edge(3,6)) is_edge(edge(5,6)) is_edge(edge(1,7)) is_edge(edge(4,7)) is_edge(edge(5,7)) is_edge(edge(6,7)) is_edge(edge(1,8)) is_edge(edge(3,8)) is_edge(edge(4,8)) is_edge(edge(5,9)) is_edge(edge(6,9)) is_edge(edge(7,9)) is_edge(edge(2,1)) is_edge(edge(3,1)) is_edge(edge(4,3)) is_edge(edge(5,1)) is_edge(edge(5,2)) is_edge(edge(6,4)) is_edge(edge(7,2)) is_edge(edge(7,3)) is_edge(edge(8,2)) is_edge(edge(8,5)) is_edge(edge(8,6)) is_edge(edge(8,7)) is_edge(edge(9,1)) is_edge(edge(9,2)) is_edge(edge(9,3)) is_edge(edge(9,4)) is_edge(edge(9,8))
```

Here's the (fixed) encoding

```
% tfas.asp
#show is_edge/1.
vertex(1..n).

opp_edges(edge(A,B),edge(B,A)) :- vertex(A), vertex(B), A < B.
possible_edge(E1;E2) :- opp_edges(E1,E2).

{is_edge(E1); is_edge(E2)} = 1 :- opp_edges(E1, E2).
ntfas(E) :- possible_edge(E), not is_edge(E).
ntfas(edge(X, X)) :- vertex(X).

tfas(E) | fs(E) :- is_edge(E).
ntfas(E) :- fs(E).

broken :- ntfas(edge(A,C)), tfas(edge(A, B)), tfas(edge(B,C)).

reachable(X, Y) :- fs(edge(X, Y)), is_edge(edge(X, Y)).
reachable(X, Z) :- reachable(X, Y), fs(edge(Y, Z)), is_edge(edge(Y, Z)).
broken :- reachable(X, X).

tfas(E) :- broken, possible_edge(E).
fs(E) :- broken, possible_edge(E).
:- not broken.
```

Run it with `clingo -c n=7 tfas.asp` (Using clingo 4.2.1)

(the n=7 indicates graphs of exactly 7 vertices)

It should return satisfiable if and only if there exists a graph with no TFAS on 7 vertices.

---

Ok, I figured out what graph @G.Bach was describing and coded it up in clingo (see the clingo description below.  It starts with a description of the gadget graph and proceeds to describe how to join copies of it together to get the full 34-vertex tournament graph G.Bach is describing.  I've attached the grounded graph description as well).

I then proceeded to run clingo on that graph and it claimed to have found a TFAS with 241 edges.  But I made a mistake in the graph encoding.  I fixed the mistake and clingo now reports unsatisfiable (ie there is no TFAS).

Here's the program for finding TFAS's on a graph

```
{tfas(E)} :- is_edge(E).
:- not tfas(edge(A,C)), tfas(edge(A, B)), tfas(edge(B,C)).

reachable(X, Y) :- not tfas(edge(X, Y)), is_edge(edge(X, Y)).
reachable(X, Z) :- reachable(X, Y), not tfas(edge(Y, Z)), is_edge(edge(Y, Z)).
:- reachable(X, X).

tfas_count(N) :- N = #count{tfas(E) : tfas(E)}.

#show tfas/1.
#show tfas_count/1.
```

Here's the (updated) program for generating G.Bach's graph.  I added indicators at the end to check that the graph is a well-formed tournament graph:

```
gadget_vertex(0..7).

gadget_edge(0,1).
gadget_edge(0,2).
gadget_edge(0,3).
gadget_edge(0,4).
gadget_edge(1,2).
gadget_edge(1,3).
gadget_edge(1,6).
gadget_edge(1,7).
gadget_edge(2,3).
gadget_edge(2,4).
gadget_edge(2,5).
gadget_edge(2,7).
gadget_edge(3,4).
gadget_edge(3,5).
gadget_edge(3,6).
gadget_edge(4,1).
gadget_edge(4,5).
gadget_edge(4,6).
gadget_edge(4,7).
gadget_edge(5,0).
gadget_edge(5,1).
gadget_edge(5,6).
gadget_edge(6,0).
gadget_edge(6,2).
gadget_edge(6,7).
gadget_edge(7,0).
gadget_edge(7,3).
gadget_edge(7,5).

special_edge(a;b;c;d;e).

forces(a,b).
forces(b,c).
forcesn(c,a).
nforces(a,d).
forces(d,e).
forces(e,a).

relates(A,B) :- forces(A,B).
relates(A,B) :- nforces(A,B).
relates(A,B) :- forcesn(A,B).

is_se_pair(se_pair(A,B)) :- relates(A,B).
vertex_name(v(V,P)) :- gadget_vertex(V), is_se_pair(P).

matches(from(A), v(5, se_pair(A,B))) :- forces(A,B).
matches(to(A), v(1, se_pair(A,B))) :- forces(A,B).
matches(from(B), v(3, se_pair(A,B))) :- forces(A,B).
matches(to(B), v(6, se_pair(A,B))) :- forces(A,B).

matches(from(A), v(2, se_pair(A,B))) :- nforces(A,B).
matches(to(A), v(7, se_pair(A,B))) :- nforces(A,B).
matches(from(B), v(1, se_pair(A,B))) :- nforces(A,B).
matches(to(B), v(3, se_pair(A,B))) :- nforces(A,B).

matches(from(A), v(7, se_pair(A,B))) :- forcesn(A,B).
matches(to(A), v(3, se_pair(A,B))) :- forcesn(A,B).
matches(from(B), v(5, se_pair(A,B))) :- forcesn(A,B).
matches(to(B), v(1, se_pair(A,B))) :- forcesn(A,B).

same_vertex(V, V) :- vertex_name(V).
same_vertex(M, N; N, M) :- matches(X, M), matches(X, N).

already_found(v(Y,N2)) :- vertex_name(v(X,N1)), same_vertex(v(X,N1),v(Y,N2)), N1 < N2.
vertex(V) :- vertex_name(V), not already_found(V).

named_gadget_edge(edge(v(X,SE),v(Y,SE))) :- gadget_edge(X,Y), is_se_pair(SE).
from_gadget_edge_named(edge(A, B), edge(C,D)) :- named_gadget_edge(edge(C,D)), same_vertex(A,C), same_vertex(B,D), vertex(A), vertex(B).
from_gadget_edge(edge(A,B)) :- from_gadget_edge_named(edge(A,B),edge(C,D)).
is_edge(E) :- from_gadget_edge(E).
is_edge(edge(A,B)) :- vertex(A), vertex(B), A < B, not from_gadget_edge(edge(B,A)).

vertex_count(VN) :- VN = #count{vertex(V) : vertex(V)}.
edge_count(EN) :- EN = #count{is_edge(E) : is_edge(E)}.

#show vertex_count/1.
#show edge_count/1.

bidirectional :- is_edge(edge(A,B)), is_edge(edge(B,A)).
phantom_vertex :- is_edge(edge(A,B)), not vertex(A).
phantom_vertex :- is_edge(edge(A,B)), not vertex(B).
incomplete :- vertex(A), vertex(B), not is_edge(edge(A,B)), not is_edge(edge(B,A)), A != B.

#show bidirectional/0.
#show phantom_vertex/0.
#show incomplete/0.
```

Comment: I'm positive there is a tournament on 18 vertices that doesn't have a TFAS.

Comment: Can you please give it as an example?  Just attach a file with the edges listed

Comment: How do I attach a file? It may take a few hours, I don't have the tournament to hand right now. I also miscalculated, it should have 34 vertices. It's probably easier to verify if I give the building blocks of the tournament.

Comment: Upload to any file host and link to it (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4643/185877), or if it has a regular structure, just describe it (give the building blocks)

Comment: cant follow your code yet but youre asserting that you are validating for finite n≤20? last sentence which asserts it is true for all $n$... if so quite remarkable(!) but not a "solution" to the general question (which would require a proof of all size cases). ps ***thx*** for working/posting an empirical observation to this site which in general is ***rare*** ... @G.Bach it would be great to see an image of the graph rather than just edge/vertex lists if possible

Comment: @dspyz I just posted an answer describing the construction of a tournament that doesn't have a transitive feedback arc set. I actually construct a digraph that isn't a tournament, but any completion of it cannot have a TFAS either. I'm sceptical you could have checked all isomorphism classes over 20 vertices; those should be an astronomically large number of tournaments.

Comment: @vzn I recognize this is not a solution, but I thought the OP would be interested to know this.  Furthermore, the comment area doesn't provide enough space (or the ability to include newlines) to say this.  Plus I saw your SWAG conjecture which is also not a solution, just a SWAG conjecture.  And this lends support to it (although I'm still convinced there's a bug in clingo.  I sent a message to the potassco mailing list asking them to take a look at this problem)

Comment: @G.Bach Modern SAT solvers (or in this case ASP solvers) use techniques which allow them to prune large portions of the search space.  This is why it's generally possible to solve SAT instances with up to thousands of variables.  Despite not actually visiting every single tournament graph on 20 vertices (exactly 20, not up to 20, to check other sizes, you'll need to input other values of n), this code still checks if there exists one without a TFAS (or at least it should. As I mentioned I'm still somewhat skeptical that there might be a bug in this latest version of clingo).

Comment: oops rereading & reinterpreting realize you mean in last sentence that the solver is solving one _instance_ of the problem quickly or instances up to $n$ only, earlier interpreted it to mean that you'd solved the complete problem posed in the question (which relates to all $n$). yes of course the conjecture is not pretending to be any solution, just a "base of further operations", and stated in comments below its apparently false (GB states below he knew as much when he posted the question)

Comment: @vzn this code is probably easier to understand if you're familliar with the proof that disjunctive ASP is Sigma-2 complete (can't find a ref. right now).  It follows the same pattern of asserting the disjunction a | b (in this case tfas | fs for each edge), and then having the negation of the clause (tfas is transitive and fs is acyclic) force both a and b so that the solution set is only minimal if the negation doesn't hold for any set of atoms (because all such sets would be subsets)

Comment: it sounds like you need some way to validate the pruning that the algorithm is doing ie some kind of "debug output" that can be examined/ verified & isolate where mistake is being made if there is indeed bug, or rule out such a defect. dont know this system much but its an obvious design criteria that all its users would want/benefit from. thx for the ref to this code, it is the 1st have seen it on this entire site, looks very interesting, intend to delve into it further, looks powerful & like it could be used for all kinds of various problems/investigations....

Comment: Actually, some newer ASP solvers can produce proofs when they return UNSAT.  I don't know if clingo can.  I sent an email to the potassco users mailing list asking them to take a look at this.  If I could understand @G.Bach's counter-example graph, I would have much stronger evidence that there is indeed a bug.  I could also probably use it to help trace the origin of that bug.

Comment: how long does the $n=20$ case take to run? is that the highest $n$ youve tried? are there any papers that talk about doing induction based on the results for all $n<m$ and succeed, ie obtain actual proofs for all $n$?

Comment: It's all parsing/grounding time (which should be cubic in the number of vertices).  At 100 vertices on my crappy old laptop, that's around 18 seconds.  In all cases I've tried, the actual solving time seems to be negligible (hence my skepticism)

Comment: Is there a way to extract just the edges from the TFAS that clingo produces? I'm very much interested to see this, especially since if the graph I described really does have a TFAS, then I can't see what's wrong with my reasoning that it shouldn't have one.

Comment: Yes, the edges are listed in http://wikisend.com/download/757898/tfas.res
also I'm as confused as you are.  As far as I can tell, your proof is sound.  And I checked that your claim does indeed hold on the gadget graph (replacing (6,3) with (3,6)).  I'll try to look into it a little deeper later.

Comment: Also, sorry about the long wordy vertex names.  They're an artifact of the way in which the graph was constructed

Answer (score 0):

[SWAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_Wild-Ass_Guess) conjecture [something better than nothing?]:

> Given a tournament $G = (V,E)$, there exists a feedback arc set $F \subseteq E$ in $G$ that defines a transitive relation. hence the problem is $O(1)$

<sup>notes: shootdown counterexamples welcome! none seem to be given so far. even better would be some observations of patterns of edge orientations related to particular graph classes. or some more motivation or tieing it into some existing literature. offered in the style of [Proofs and refutations](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521290384) (Lakatos)... also, since it seems such an offbeat problem that doesnt [yet?] relate to much, suggest studying it empirically....</sup>

Comment: I did run a program to check whether this holds and found that there are tournaments that do not have a transitive feedback arc set. I'll post one tomorrow, I won't get around to it today.

Comment: @vzn can you prove the conjecture for a random tournament?

Comment: Counterexample with only 5 vertices: a->b, a->c, b->c, d->a, b->d, c->d, e->a, e->b, c->e, d->e.  For any four vertices, the induced graph contains a cycle, so a transitive DAG can contain at most 3 edges among 3 vertices of the graph.  There are only 5 possibilities (all other triplets are cycles): abc,eab,dea,bcd,cde  It's easy to check that in each of the five cases there is a cycle among the other 7 edges

Comment: Oh wait, I forgot that you can also include the edge between the other two vertices without breaking transitivity.  Now I'm not sure

Comment: Yeah, nvr mind, it's not a counterexample

Comment: @dspyz I ran a brute force check on all tournaments on up to 8 vertices. All of them have transitive feedback arc sets, but there are some you can use to build a tournament that doesn't.

Comment: @dspyz / GB thx for further look & your further effort is interesting. the conjecture is almost not based on any analysis at all but merely a possibly easily-overturned "stake"
to spur something further and an "empirical experiment" to see what will happen to the bounty/ dont want it to go to waste **=D** ... might be interested to put further thought/effort into this (like the DAG restatement) but feel there is insufficient bkg/motivation on it so far [am all open ears if gb would care to elaborate]... [chat on it sometime anyone?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9446/theory-salon)

Comment: @vzn In case you're still curious, I posted an answer describing the construction of a tournament that doesn't have a transitive feedback arc set.

Comment: @g.bach interesting graph. new revised conjecture, for some $m$ all graphs $n<m$ vertices have a TFAS **=D** ... wonder if the pairwise disjoint edge/implication idea can generate all non-TFAS graphs...

Comment: @vzn I verified that conjecture for $m = 8$ when I was looking for that tournament I gave.

Comment: @g.bach ok did you know all this when you posted the question? if so itd be helpful to include it.

Comment: @vzn I did, but I purposely didn't include it because I was worried that information might get people stuck the same way it got me stuck. Not knowing something allows more creativity sometimes, at least that's what I thought.

Comment: @G.Bach agreed, sometimes, but it can also help solving the problem based on all/full info known so far and avoiding immediately wrong ideas such as the one posted...! also my revised conjecture cannot be proven/verified empirically, again due to same issue raised on dspyz's answer. or rather, meant to include also in the new conjecture that all $n>m$ have at least one non-TFAS graph.