# looking for notable applications of ASP (Answer Set Programming) in TCS

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, big-picture, application-of-theory, proof-assistants

a recent difficult question of interest to the group[1] by [GB](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/8871/g-bach) has possibly led to verification of a new graph property by [dspyz](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/13643/dspyz), by use of [Answer Set Programming/ASP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Answer_set_programming). via sophisticated logic principles/algorithms remarkably this software can verify a complex property of graphs apparently without enumerating all isomorphisms. there does not seem to be much prior ref to this software & logic/theorem proving research on tcs.se.

> looking for notable papers that use ASP from a TCS pov to investigate important problems in the area.

even better would be anything that relates it to inductive proofs of graph properties in automated theorem proving.[5] (some misc refs [2-4] to the software utilized are included below.)

[1] [Transitive feedback arc set (TFAS): NP-complete?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20661/transitive-feedback-arc-set-tfas-np-complete)
[2] [Potassco: The Potsdam Answer Set Solving Collection](http://www.cs.uni-potsdam.de/wv/pdfformat/gekakaosscsc11a.pdf) Gebser et al
[3] [Potassco/sourceforge](http://potassco.sourceforge.net/)
[4] [ASP tools users guide](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~vl/teaching/lbai/clingo_guide.pdf) Gebser et al
[5] [techniques or examples of analyzing a series of graphs](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/11131/techniques-or-examples-of-analyzing-a-series-of-graphs), tcs.se

Comment: For examples, you might be interested in [these slides](http://satsmt2013.ics.aalto.fi/slides/Schaub.pdf) from a recent talk. There is also indeed [a book for applying ASP in practice](http://potassco.sourceforge.net/book.html).